# PHP variable falls outside the scope of Javascript, how do I get it in the scope?

Tags: javascript, php, html

I'm trying to make a dropdown in HTML, but I want to have it's default value to be determined by the value of a PHP variable. I wanted to do it with JavaScript, but I end up with the famous "Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined" error :/.

PHP:

```
while(list($ArtikelID, $Type) = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
  $arid = $ArtikelID;
  $te = $Type;
}
```

HTML + JS:

```
<form name="send" method="post" action="editartticlesdef.php">
    articlenumber: </br>
    <input readonly="readonly" name="ArticleID" value=<?php echo $arid ?>></br>
    Type: </br>
    <select name="Type">
        <option value="Article">Article</option>
        <option value="Code">Code</option>
        <option value="News">News</option>
        <option value="Project">Project</option>
    </select></br>
    <script>
        document.getElementById("Type").selectedIndex = <?php echo '$te'; ?>;
    </script>
</form>
```

I tried to place the script on other places on the page but had no success :/. I suspect the variable falls outside the scope, but I don't know how to get it back in :/.

Comment: Replace `<?php echo '$te'; ?>` with `'<?php echo $te; ?>'`

Comment: Is PHP or JavaScript throwing the error?  What is the resulting JavaScript created by this code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It should be -

```
<select name="Type" id="Type">
```

And

```
document.getElementById("Type").selectedIndex = '<?php echo $te; ?>';
```

Comment: Well that worked, but it turns out I'm also an idiot. While this solves the error I got it also shows me that I'm trying to select the value of the dropdown by id and not the value of the variable $te. *facepalm*

Answer (score 1):

Provided `$te` is an integer between 0 and 3, then you need to:

1. Give your select an id attribute:

   `<select name="Type" id="Type">
          <option value="Article">Article</option>
          <option value="Code">Code</option>
          <option value="News">News</option>
          <option value="Project">Project</option>
    </select>`
2. remove the quotes areound the php variable itsself and place them in the html:

   `<script>
       document.getElementById("Type").selectedIndex = "<?php echo $te; ?>";
   </script>`

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for not answering the question, but you should not use mysql_, it's deprecated and unsafe (See [PHP Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php)). Use MySQLi or PDO.